# Customize Control center Swift and IOS 9+

Tags: ios, swift, control-center

friends I am working on an ios app using Swift, I am suppose to add app icon in Control Center and also on any web page user should be able to select text or paragraph and save that text in the application.

I just need a hint or starting point, I am sort of new to IOS, have built 3-4 apps but never worked on Control Center and adding service which allow copy and save text and images from iphone browser.

Answer (score 2):

Control Center is not extensible in iOS. There is no api for it.

Comment: The spotify app add custom controls to the Control Center. Maybe I'm wrong and this is not the Control Center.